# Change User-Agent for Google IAM in Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-iam

Is it possible to change user-agent information for API calls to Google IAM when we instantiate it? My code is like this:

```
    public static Iam initIam() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        InputStream resourceAsStream = GoogleIAM.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("creds.txt");
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(resourceAsStream);

        httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
            List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
            // Enable full Cloud Platform scope.
            scopes.add(IamScopes.CLOUD_PLATFORM);
            credential = credential.createScoped(scopes);
        }

        // Create IAM API object associated with the authenticated transport.
        return new Iam.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("test").build();
    }
```

I saw that for Google Storage is possible using HeaderProvider like this:

```
        Map<String, String> m = ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder().put("user-agent", "my custom useragent").build();
        HeaderProvider headerProvider = FixedHeaderProvider.create(m);
```

but I couldn't find out how to use HeaderProvider in Google IAM.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually already done in the code

> return new Iam.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY,
>   credential).setApplicationName("test").build();

with the setApplicationName method wherein the Stackdriver log you can see that the application name, i.e. test, will be there in the user-agent field